# page pushed more than once in the navigation stack upon publishing events Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my Ionic app I have a meetings page as a landing page. Upon landing on this page I am subscribing to an event in the constructor which will in call a function when published.

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
     private commServe: Communication, private currentUser: CurrentUser, 
     private utility: Utility,
     private popOverController: PopoverController, private _events: Events, 
     private _alert: AlertController) {
     this._events.subscribe("navigate-notification", (type, meetingId, 
     notificationId) => {
      this.navigateNotification(type, meetingId, notificationId);
});

 navigateNotification(type, meetingId, notificationId): void {
 this.navCtrl.push("MyMeeting", {
   "meetingId": meetingId,
   "notificationId": notificationId
 });
}
```

When I open a notifications popover I retrieve a meetingId, notificationId and type of notification and publish the event in the meetings page, the purpose as evident in the code is then to navigate to the relevant meeting referenced in the notification.

```
  goToComponent(type, meetingId, notificationId) {
   console.log(meetingId);
    this._events.publish("navigate-notification", type, meetingId, 
     notificationId);

  }
 this.currentView.dismiss();
```

this.currentView.dismiss() is an instance of ViewController which dismisses the popover.
This all is fine, the problem I have is that the page(the user is navigates to) pushes on top of the landing page several times (3-4 times).

Why is that and how can I rectify this.

Regards

Comment: Instead of `this.navigateNotification...` if you just set a debugger, could you please check if that event is being published more than once?

Comment: Yes, it does publish more once. It 'fires' of several times

Comment: Could you please add some more code of when and how the event is being published?

Comment: I updated it a bit, The event is fired when user taps on the notification which in turn calls the function goToComponent()

Comment: That `console.log(meetingId);` is being fired once or more than once?

Comment: That interestingly fires of only once, it is the `navigateNotification` that fires of several times

Comment: Could you please set a debugger in the constructor, right before the `this._events.subscribe("navigate-notification"....` line, to see if the component is subscribing to the event more than once?

Comment: I did, it subscribes to the event only once

Comment: Look at the events objects and how many listeners does it have? This should answer whether you are over subscribing or over publishing

Comment: Thanks for your help `sebaferreras`. The best solution I could think of was to unsubscribe before subscribing. That solved it. `this._events.unsubscribe("navigate-notification");` `this._events.subscribe("navigate-notification"...`